# How to make animated text-decoration underline on hover

Tags: html, css

I was able to apply `background-image` to anchor on `:hover` and now want it to be animated at the same time. How can I possibly achieve that?

[image]

```
.nav-content ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-content ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('dotted.gif') bottom repeat-x;
}
```

> Clarifying my question:

What I am trying to achieve is that the underline `dotted.gif` image to be animated on the X axis continuously on hover. So far it just appears on hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with `transition` and `opacity` for fade in/fade out, and also `animation` and `background-position` for moving dotes along X-axis, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/kLoL8t6f/3/):

```css
.link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

    .link:after {
        content: ''; 
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 3px;
        background: url('http://oi62.tinypic.com/256wzvb.jpg');
        background-size: 120px 120px;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -webkit-animation: x-move 5s linear infinite; 
        animation: x-move 5s linear infinite;
    }

    .link:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .link:hover:after {
            opacity: 1;
        }

@-webkit-keyframes x-move {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 120px 0; }
}

@keyframes x-move {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 120px 0; }
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Test link</a>
```

Comment: I have the same effect already I wanted it to be animated on X axis like looping effect

Comment: @alpha there is no animation in your example's code. You should specify your question then.

Comment: I meant when you hover over link I have the same effect what you provided ... I want underline to be animated continuously on X axis when you hover

Comment: @alpha I improved my answer, check it out please.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
.link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.link:after {
    content: ''; 
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #e0d16c;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
    transition: width 0.2s;
}

.link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: black; width: 200px; height: 100px; padding: 10px;">
    <a class="link" href="#">Test link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that crossed my mind at the beginning ... How about instead of sliding its width just animate dotted.gif image like a horizontal line continuously? I upvoted for your efforts but the answer above is my solution thanks again